# primefaces 4.0 actionListener commandbutton don't work

Tags: java, primefaces, actionlistener, commandbutton

http://pastebin.com/5Nvn1uSB this is my xhtml

http://pastebin.com/fqwiRQER this is home there is the code for menuitems that dont work...

http://pastebin.com/Phun7EKS this is registration with connection to db... but doesn't work at all not even running it

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see lots of issues here. First, your description of what's happening is non-existent. It's pretty hard to help you when all you provide is code without a good description of your environment, what you expect to happen and what's actually happening.

Also, it would be helpful to know what steps you have already taken to debug your code.

That said, based on a quick read of your code, your `p:commandButton` is using an `actionListener` instead of an `action` which I believe is the correct attribute.

Lastly, you're using raw text fields from your web page to directly build an SQL statement. This opens you up to all kinds of code injection exploits that you probably want to avoid. You'd be better off using something like JPA as an abstraction layer that allows you to persist objects.